# Вывод товаров со скидкой OCStore

Tags: php, opencart

Каким образом осуществить вывод **всех** товаров со скидкой на отдельной странице, не зависимо от выбранной категории?
Версия ocStore 2.1.0.2

Вот каким образом происходит вывод во всех категориях:

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {
    $customer_group_id = $this->getCustomerGroup();

    $sql = "SELECT product_id, round((1-realprice/price)*100) as discount FROM (SELECT p.product_id, s.revalention, p.date_available, p.price,";
    $sql .= " (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating,";
    $sql .= " coalesce((SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1),"
        ." (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1),"
        ." p.price) as realprice";

    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])){
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_option'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov ON (p.product_id = pov.product_id)";
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
    }

    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "statistic s ON (s.product_id = p.product_id) AND date = CURDATE() ";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        } else {
            $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . $data['filter_filter'] . ")";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_option'])) {
            $sql .= " AND pov.option_value_id IN (" . $data['filter_option'] . ") AND (pov.quantity > 0 OR pov.quantity is null)";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
    }

    if ($data['min_price']) {
        $sql .= " AND p.price >= '" . (int)$data['min_price'] . "'";
    }

    $sql .= ") as sub WHERE 1=1";

    if ($data['min_price']) {
        $sql .= " AND realprice >= '" . (int)$data['min_price'] . "'";
    }

    if ($data['max_price']) {
        $sql .= " AND realprice <= '" . (int)$data['max_price'] . "'";
    }

    if ($data['filter_special']) {
        $sql .= " AND realprice < price";
    }

    $sql .= " GROUP BY product_id";

    $sort_data = array(
        'p.price',
        'date_available',
        'rating',
        'discount',
        'revalention',
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        if ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY realprice";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY revalention DESC";
    }

    if (isset($data['order'])) {
        $sql .= " " . $data['order'];
    }

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $product_data = array();

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }

    return $sql;
}
```

Я создал категорию Скидки (id = 82) и хотелось бы именно в эту категорию выводить все товары, у которых есть скидка, но так же, что бы и работали фильтры. Предполагаю что нужно составить грамотный sql-запрос. Но в opencart'е слишком сложные они (для меня).

Comment: Вы про скидки для групп покупателей от количества товаров или про товары по акции?

Comment: Товары со скидкой. Они одинаковы для всех пользователей.